# Why does my function return two values when I only return one?

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I'm trying to implement the Simpson method in Matlab, this is my code:

```
function q = simpson(x,f)
n = size(x);
%subtracting the last value of the x vector with the first one
ba = x(n) - x(1);

%adding all the values of the f vector which are in even places starting from f(2)
a = 2*f(2:2:end-1);
%adding all the values of the f vector which are in odd places starting from 1
b = 4*f(1:2:end-1);

%the result is the Simpson approximation of the values given
q = ((ba)/3*n)*(f(1) + f(n) + a + b);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

For some reason even if I set q to be

```
q = f(n)
```

As a result I get:

```
q =

 0     1
```

Instead of

```
q =

 0
```

When I set q to be

```
q = f(1)
```

I get:

```
q =

 0


q =

 0
```

I can't explain this behavior, that's probably why I get the error mentioned above. So why does q have two values instead of one?

edit: `x = linspace(0,pi/2,12);
       f = sin(x);`

Comment: what is this f variable? Which line are you getting the error? You haven't even show what f actually is. You are getting your results based on what you have in your `f`

Comment: I edited my post and added my x and f. i get the error in the line where I try to compute q.

Comment: So I changed `a` and `b` to `a = sum(f(2:2:end-1));
b = sum(4*f(1:2:end-1));` and after a test run `a = 3.0133` and `b =  13.9103` but I still get the same error when I try to compute q. Maybe the f's are the problem. How to I access the first and last value of f without messing it up?

Comment: try changing the line `n=size(x)` to `n=size(x,1)`.

Comment: Well when I changed it to `n=size(x,1)` I get `q = 0` because the result of `size(x,1)` is `1` I changed it to `n=size(x,2)` and I got `n = 12` which is the size of `x`. Now I get `q=112.6176`.

Comment: `size(x, 1)` assumes that x is a column vector, `size(x, 2)` assumes that it is a row vector. Make it generic by using `numel(x)` instead, or by explicitly reshaping x, e.g. `x = x(:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size(x)` returns the size of the array. This will be a vector with all the dimensions of the matrix. **There must be at least two dimensions**.

In your case `n=size(x)` will give n=[N, 1], not just the length of the array as you desire. This will mean than ba will have 2 elements.

You can fix this be using `length(x)` which returns the longest dimension rather than size (or `numel(x)` or `size(x, 1)` or 2 depending on how x is defined which returns only the numbered dimension).

Also you want to sum over in a and b whereas now you just create an vector with these elements in. try changing it to `a=2*sum(f(...))` and similar for b.

The error occurs because you are doing matrix multiplication of two vectors with different dimensions which isn't allowed. If you change the code all the values should be scalars so it should work.

To get the correct answer (3*n) should also be in brackets as matlab doesn't prefer between / and * (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html). Your version does (ba/3)*n which is wrong.

Comment: `length` may lead to problems, too. Better to use `numel`. See my comment on the question.

Comment: The thing is that as a result I get `q = 112.6176` while the integral of `sin(x)` with upper and lower bounds being `pi/2` and `0` should be `1` and not `112.6176`...

Comment: (3*n) needs to be in brackets. I've never understood how matlab orders these things.